# How to get the correct absolute file path after maven project is deployed

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Say I have a maven web application that in my `src/main/resources` folder I have a `.txt` file.

My goal is to get the absolute path of this file after building and deploying the project to Tomcat.

Currently my Java code set up is something like this:

```
File file = new File("scr/main/resources/test.txt");
String absolutePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
```

It looks this does not work, the `absolutePath` path I am getting includes the tomcat path, like this:

> "C:\Dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\bin\scr\main\resources\test.txt"

However the correct file absolute path location is:

> "C:\Dev\NetBeansProjects\MavenWebApp\src\main\resources\test.txt"

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a file under `src/main/resources`, you can rely on the classloader to load it:

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("/test.txt");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: I am not trying to get the file, I am trying to get the absolute path of the `text.txt` file, which located under src/main/resources.

Comment: @JasonZ You can do this using the returned URL.